# accessing variables in different functions

Tags: php

so this is my code

```
function func_readmsg () {
    $targetmessage = $_POST['inquiry_no'];
    $result = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbbyahenijuan"),
         "SELECT * FROM tblinquiry where finquiry_no='$targetmessage' ");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        global $sender, $message, $date;
        $sender = $row['ffull_name'];
        $message = $row['fmessage'];
        $date = $row['fdate'];
    }
    echo "
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#messagewindow').fadeIn('show');
        });
    </script>";
}

function func_delmsg () {
    echo $targetmessage;
}
```

I need to transfer or read the value of `$targetmessage` from `func_readmsg` to `func_delmsg`.
I have already tried `$GLOBALS['targetmessage']`, `global $targetmessage`. Please help.

Comment: Please format your code with Ctrl + K.

Comment: You can pass your variable as a parameter to your function!

Answer (score 0):

declare your variable `$targetmessage;` outside of any php functions, when you want to access to this variable for R/W, inside your function, you have to do like that `global $targetmessage;`

Comment: Using globals really is considered bad practise.... it is not a universal panacea to any scope problem

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable to the other function or make them part of a class:

```
<?php
class MessageClass
    {
        public $targetmessage;

        public function func_readmsg() {
            $this->targetmessage = $_POST['inquiry_no'];
            $result = mysqli_query(mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbbyahenijuan"),
                 "SELECT * FROM tblinquiry where finquiry_no='".$this->targetmessage."'");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                global $sender, $message, $date;
                $sender = $row['ffull_name'];
                $message = $row['fmessage'];
                $date = $row['fdate'];
            } ?>
             <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#messagewindow').fadeIn('show');
                    });
             </script><?php
        }

        public  function func_delmsg() {
            echo $this->targetmessage;
            }
    }

// To implement
$reader = new MessageClass();
// Function 1
$reader->func_readmsg();
// Function 2
$reader->func_delmsg(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

is it inside a session ? use session vars. $_SESSION['targetmessage'];

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to do this would be to pass the message as an argument to your functions:

```
$targetmessage = $_POST['inquiry_no'];

// run func_readmsg on $targetmessage
func_readmsg($targetmessage);

// now do something else with it
func_delmsg($targetmessage);


function func_readmsg ($message) {
    // do stuff with $message
}

function func_delmsg ($message) {
    echo $message;
}
```

The PHP manual has plenty of documentation on [how to write functions and use arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [global variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Add `global $targetmessage;` at the beginning of both functions. Take care of side-effects: that variable will be also accessible from everywhere else.

Don't forget to call the first one before the second one, otherwise, `$targetmessage` won't be defined.

*Example:*

```
function foo()
{
    global $var;
    $var = 'foo';
    var_dump($var);
}
function bar()
{
    global $var;
    var_dump($var);
}

foo();
bar();
```

*Final note*:

you should actually use a parameter instead of a global variable: `function func_readmsg($targetmessage)` and `function func_delmsg($targetmessage)`, then pass the value of `$targetmessage` as a parameter when you call the functions.

---

SQL injection spotted:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblinquiry where finquiry_no='$targetmessage' "
```

What if `$_POST['inquiry_no']` is `' OR 1='1` ?